# How to access class variables from inner prototype - javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I might not be clear with my title of the question. Sorry for that.

Here is what I wanted to do.

I'm trying to use prototyping pattern in javascript. I created a class as following.

```
var MyClass = null;
(function() {
    MyClass = function() {
        this.clsVar = "I'm inside constructor";
    };

    MyClass.prototype = {
        constructor: MyClass,
        myFunc1: function() {
            console.log("I'm func1 accessing constructor variable : " + this.clsVar);
        },
        nested: {
            myFunc2: function() {
                console.log("I'm func2 accessing constructor variable : " + this.clsVar); // I know, this will never point to the class scope
            }
        }
    }
}())
```

I'm creating an object.

```
var my = new MyClass();

my.myFunc1(); // which prints "I'm func1 accessing constructor variable : I'm inside constructor" 

my.nested.myFunc1(); // as expected, it prints "I'm func2 accessing constructor variable : undefined
```

All I am trying to do is, I should be able to access `clsVar` from `nested.myFunc2`

is that possible.? Any help is greatly appreciated and needed. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a point.

The `this`  inside your `myFunc2` does not refer anymore to `MyClass` but to another context. So, the fastest way is to do is to use `call` or `apply` like:

```
var myNewObject = new MyClass();
myNewObject.nested.myFunc2.call(myNewObject, arg1, arg2);
```

or

```
myNewObject.nested.myFunc2.apply(myNewObject, [arg1, arg2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's prototype-based class system does not allow this. 
MyClass's prototype will be shared between all instances of the class. In the following code, both instances will use the same function instance...

```
var first = new MyClass(), second = new MyClass();
first.nested.myFunc2(); <-- Same prototype function
seecond.nested.myFunc2(); <-- Same prototype function
```

When the code enters the "myFunc2" definition, which parent should it be accessing?

If you need access to the parent's "this" value, you'll have to use a closure and set up the nested object in the parent constructor as below.

```
var MyClass = null;

(function() {
    MyClass = function() {
        this.clsVar = "I'm inside constructor";
        var that = this;
        this.nested = {
            myFunc2: function() {
                console.log("I'm func2 accessing constructor variable : " + that.clsVar); // I know, this will never point to the class scope
            }
         }
    };

    MyClass.prototype = {
        constructor: MyClass,
        myFunc1: function() {
            console.log("I'm func1 accessing constructor variable : " + this.clsVar);
        }
    }
}())
```